# What is the right way for multiple api call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I'm doing a project that updates many patients' information with axios call. I parsed the patient's csv file to JSON format. And, call post api to update each patient's information like below.

```js
/**
* this.csvJson.data : List of JSON format, each json contain one patient's information
*/
.
.
await this.csvJson.data.map(async (data)=>{
            await axios.post(`api/MetaData/${this.projects.projectId}`,data)
                .then(response=>{
                    //response handling
                })
                .catch(error=>{
                   //error handling
                })
        })
.
.
```

In this case, when the patient number is below 200, the uploading process is comparatively stable. But when patients number is over 20000, Browser has no response. I think calling multiple api for each patient cause browser crash.

What is the right way for handling multiple api call like this?

Comment: Is your code dependent on the async await logic?

Comment: Yes, i have to wait until axios get response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that code you are making 20000 requests in an instant no wonder the browser is crashing. since you're using already an external library you can take a look at [fastq](https://github.com/mcollina/fastq).

Heres my implementation in React, basically fastq can take the each params of each request then wrap each of it in an async worker function then it will only do "*concurrency*" number of request at a time. If you make a 20000 requests depending on how fast the requests is made it would take time to finish. you may want to add more concurrency to make it faster.

```js
import fastq from "fastq";

export async function consecutiveRequest(data, requester, concurrency = 10) {
  const workerFunction= async (args) => {
    try {
      const data = await requester(args.params);
      console.log(args.index, "Requested:", args, "Result:", data);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return null;
    }
  };

  const consecutiveQueue = fastq.promise(
    workerFunction, // fastq take a worker function 
    concurrency // number of requests only allowed at a time
  );

  const req = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const params = data[i];
    req.push(consecutiveQueue.push({ params, index: i }));
  }

  let data = await Promise.all(req);
  return data;
}
```

```js
import _ from "lodash";
import React from "react";
import { consecutiveRequest } from "./request";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const randomNumbers = _.range(0, 50).map(() => _.random(0, 4));
  const [results, setResults] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);

  const handleSendQueueRequest = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const res = await consecutiveRequest(
      randomNumbers,
      async (random) => {
        const url = `https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts`;
        const res = await fetch(url, { method: "GET" });
        const json = await res.json();
        const facts = json || [];
        return facts[random]?.text;
      },
      10
    );
    setResults(res);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button disabled={loading} onClick={handleSendQueueRequest}>
        {loading ? "Loading" : "Get Random Quote"}
      </button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(results, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Heres the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-moon-hkwvu) take a look in the console on how its working.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple apiCall using Promise.all is often a better otpion, but i dont know if it can handle 20 000requests

```js
  const promises = csvJsonData.map((patientData) => {
    return axios.post(`api/MetaData/${this.projects.projectId}`, data);
  });

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then((response) => {
      //response handling
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      //error handling
    });
```